# A topological property of shapes like $\bot$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a shape like $\bot$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Is it possible to construct a continuous function $f : X\times X \longrightarrow X$ such that for any $v,w \in X$, $f(v,w) = f(w,v) \in \{v,w\}$ ?

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: I am not sure about the origin. But for me I have been told by a friend of mine when we were in summer camp.

Comment: I think this works: choose some ordering of the "branches" of the shape, labeling them $b_1$, $b_2$, and $b_3$. Now if $v\in b_i$ and $w\in b_j$, and $i < j$, let $f(v,w) = f(w,v) = v$. If $v,w\in b_i$, then say $f(v,w) = f(w,v)$ is whichever one is closest to the intersection of the branches.

Comment: @Stahl: I don't think that works.  Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be the endpoints of the three branches (with corresponding labels) and consider a path $p : [0,1]\to X$ traveling from $v_1$ to $v_3$, crossing the center point at $t = 1/2$.  With your choice of $f$, we have $f(p(t),v_2) = p(t)$ whenever $t \le 1/2$, but $f(p(t),v_2) = v_2$ whenever $t > 1/2$.

Comment: @PaulMcKenney Good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

For simplicity we shall use the following description. Consider three segments $[0,1]\times\{1\}$,
$[0,1]\times\{2\}$, and  $[0,1]\times\{3\}$. We identify points $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$ and $(0,3)$ to a point $0^*$ and denote the obtained space as $X$. Put $X_i=(0,1]\times\{i\}$ for every $i$. 
We claim that there is no continuous function $f$ satisfying conditions of the question. Indeed, assume the converse. Let $i,j$ be arbitrary non-equal integers from $1$ to $3$. Since the space $X_i\times X_j$ is connected,  $f(X_i\times X_j)\subset X_i\cup X_j$, and the space $X_i\cup X_j$ is a disjoint union of its clopen (that is closed and open) subspaces $X_i$ and $X_j$, we see that there exists a number $k\in\{i,j\}$ such that $f(X_i\times X_j)\subset X_k$. Let $\{i,j\}\setminus \{k\}=\{l\}$. Therefore for all $0<x,y<1$ we have $f((x,k),(y,l))=(x,k)$. The continuity of the function $f$ implies that $f((x,k),0^*)=(x,k)$ and $f(0^*,(y,l))=0^*$. Consider now a function $g:X\to X$ defined as $g(x)=f(x,0^*)$. Then $g|X_k=\operatorname{id}$ and $g|X_l\equiv 0^*$. Let $\{1,2,3\}\setminus \{k\}=\{i’,j’\}$. Similarly to the above we can show that there exists a number $k’\in\{i',j'\}$ such that $g|X_{k’}=\operatorname{id}$. Again similarly to the above we can show that there exists a number $k’’\in\{k,k’\}$ such that $g|X_{k''}\equiv 0^*$, a contradiction, because $g|X_k=\operatorname{id}$ and $g|X_{k'}=\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: "Converse" isn't the word you mean. "Assume $f$ is such a function" will do.

Comment: @dfeuer I wrote it in such form in order to make a proof from a converse more clear.

Comment: What does it have to do with the [converse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) of anything?

Comment: @dfeuer English is not my native language. And my English book claims that I may start such proofs with the phrase “The proof is by reductio ad absurdum”, but this is somewhat old-fashioned so it is better to begin: “Assume the converse, then...”